# How to generate a PDF/E with pdflatex?

Tags: pdf, publishing

I'm interested to generate a [PDF/E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/E) subset file with pdflatex. I know the pdfx package, but it's only works with PDF/A and PDF/X.

Comment: There is a German tutorial here, using `movie15` http://www.goermezer.de/content/view/486/544/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.